# How to convert Json object date using moment js into react native?

Tags: json, react-native, date, type-conversion, momentjs

I have json object date like this "2020-02-26T21:40:47"
{{itemmap.date}}

how to convert it into something like 12 Feb, 2020
i have no clue using moment js in react native

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use my answer u get the string you want please consider approving my answer  or at least provide some feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MomentJS Docs : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

should look something like: `moment(yourDate).format("DD MMM, YYYY")`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple static example. this may help you out..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import moment from 'moment';

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dateText: '',
    };
  }

    onDOBDatePicked = (date) => {
      this.setState({
        dateText: moment(date).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
      });
    }
    componentDidMount () {
      const date = "Sun Feb 23 2020 10:12:46 GMT+0800 (CST)";
      this.onDOBDatePicked(date);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{ padding : 50 }}>
          {this.state.dateText}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.. Ask if any doubt.